# Javascript- Variable Hoisting

Tags: javascript

This is a simple snippet, I just dont understand something.

The below code outputs 12, I understand that, because the `var foo = 12;` replaces the previous declaration of the variable.

```
<script>
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
  if (!foo) {
    var foo = 12;
  }
  alert(foo);
}
bar();
</script>
```

In the below code, it alerts **1** , which means the variable declared outside the function is accessible inside the function.

```
  <script>
    var foo = 1;
    function bar(){
      alert(foo);
    }
    bar();
    </script>
```

But, in the below code, why it alerts undefined ?? I thought, it will alert **1**,  I am just assigning the previously declared variable to the new one.

```
  <script>
    var foo = 1;
    function bar(){
      if (!foo) {
        var foo = foo;
      }
      alert(foo);
    }
    bar();
    </script>
```

Comment: Use `var foo = window.foo;`

Comment: `if (!foo) {` checks global variable `foo`, but inside the `if` statement you are trying to change this global variable value with another `foo`, with is undefinied inside the `if` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable declarations are pushed to the start of the function.

Therefore in reality the following is happening:

```
function bar(){
      var foo;
      if (!foo) {
        foo = foo;
      }
      alert(foo);
}
```

Therefore you would need to change this to use `window.foo` so that you're referring to the global property rather than the function's property:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
   var foo;
   if (!window.foo) {
      foo = window.foo;
   }
   alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

Comment: the same thing happens with function expressions

Comment: got it :) Learnt something new thanx :)

Answer (score 4):

Hoisting is slightly tricky. Function declarations are hoisted with the function assignment, but variable declarations are hoisted **without** the variable assignment. So the execution order of code is actually:

```
var foo;
var bar = function bar(){
  var foo; // undefined
  if (!foo) { // true
    foo = foo; // foo = undefined
  }
  alert(foo);
}
foo = 1;
bar();
```

You could either use `window.foo` if you want to refer to the global variable `foo`, or better, just use a different variable name:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
  var baz =  foo;
  alert(baz);
}
bar();
```

Answer (score 3):

> The below code outputs 12, I understand that, because the var foo =
>   12; replaces the previous declaration of the variable.

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
  if (!foo) {
    var foo = 12;
  }
  alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

You are right because local variable overriding the global one.

> In the below code, it alerts 1 , which means the variable declared
>   outside the function is accessible inside the function.

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
  alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

You are correct. `foo` is declare in global scope so is accessible fron anywhere.

> But, in the below code, why it alerts undefined ?? I thought, it will
>   alert 1, I am just assigning the previously declared variable to the
>   new one.

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(){
  if (!foo) {
    var foo = foo;
  }
  alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

This is a bit different. You are declaring a global variable and a local one with the same name. When your JavaScript program execution enters a new function, all the variables declared anywhere in the function are moved (or elevated, or hoisted) to the top of the function.

Another example:

```js
var a = 123;

function f() {
    var a; // same as: var a = undefined;
    alert(a); // undefined
    a = 1;
    alert(a); // 1
}
f();
```

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, until the ES5 specification, the scope is implemented only in terms of **function body**. The concept of *block scope* doesn't exist ([really, will be implemented in the next javascript with the **let** keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

So, if you declare a variable `var something;` outside from function body, it will be global (in browsers global scope is the scope of the **window** object).

1. global variables

```js
var something = 'Hi Man';

/**
 * this is equal to:
**/

window.something = 'Hi Man';
```

If your code doesn't run in *[strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)*, there is another way to declare a global variable: omitting the **var** keyword. When the *var* keyword is omitted the variable belongs (or is moved) to the global scope.

2. example:

```js
something = 'Hi Man';

/**
 * this is equal to:
**/

function someFunction() {
  something = 'Hi Man';
}
```

#### Local Variables

Because the non-existence of *block scopes* the only way to declare a **local variable** is to define it in a **function body**.

3. Example

```js
var something = 'Hi Man'; //global
console.log('globalVariable', something);

function someFunction() {
  var something = 'Hi Woman';
  console.log('localVariable', something);
  
  /**
   * defining variable that doesn't exists in global scope
  **/
  var localSomething = 'Hi People';
  console.log('another local variable', localSomething);
}

someFunction();
console.log('globalVariable after function execution', something);

try {
  console.log('try to access a local variable from global scope', localSomething);
} catch(e) { console.error(e); }
```

As you can see in this example, local variables don't exist outside from their scope. This means another thing... If you declare, with the *var* keyword, the same variable in two different scopes you'll get two different variables not an override of the same variable (name) defined in the parent scope.

If you want to "override" the same variable in a **child scope** you have to use it without the *var* keyword. Because of the **[scope chain](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/)** if a variable dosn't exist in a local scope it will be searched on their parent scope.

4. Example

```js
function someFunction() {
  something = 'Hi Woman';
}

var something = 'Hi Man';
console.log(1, 'something is', something);


someFunction();
console.log(1, 'something is', something);
```

#### Last thing, variable hoistment.

As I wrote below, at the moment, there isn't any way to declare a variable in some point of your code. It is always declared at the start of it scope.

5. Example

```js
function someFunction() {
  // doing something
  
  // doing something else
  
  var something = 'Hi Man';
}


/**
 * Probably you expect that the something variable will be defined after the 'doing 
 * something else' task, but, as javascript works, it will be defined on top of it scope.
 * So, the below snippet is equal to:
**/

function someFunction1() {
  var something;
  
  // doing something
  
  // doing something else
  
  something = 'Hi Man';
}

/**
 * You can try these following examples: 
 *
 * In the someFunction2 we try to access on a non-defined variable and this throws an
 * error.
 *
 * In the someFunction3, instead, we don't get any error because the variable that we expect to define later will be hoisted and defined at the top, so, the log is a simple undefined log.
**/

function someFunction2() {
  console.log(something);
};

function someFunction3() {
  console.log('before declaration', something);
  
  var something = 'Hi Man';
  
  console.log('after declaration', something);
}
```

This happens because in javascript there are **two different** steps of a variable declaration:

- Definition
- Initialization

And the *function3* example becomes as following:

```js
function3Explained() {
  var something; // define it as undefined, this is the same as doing var something = undefined;
  
  // doing something;
  // doing something else;
  
  something = 'Hi Man';
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it doesn't have anything to do with function declaration and hoisting ,

declaring the var with `var` inside function you are creating a variable in the function's isolated scope, this is why you get undefined.

```
 var foo = 1;
 function funcOne() {
     var foo = foo;
     alert('foo is ' + foo);
 };
 funcOne();

 var bau = 1;
 function funcTwo() {
     bau = bau;
     alert('bau is ' + bau);
 };
 funcTwo();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/q23abmu4/)

Comment: This was a nice example, thanx :)